# User defined value of Initial capacity and LoadFactor for a Large HashMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a HashMap storing **millions of entries**. Now in order to avoid rehashing every time it reaches the threshold,I want to give a user defined value of Initial capacity and Load factor so that rehashing is bare minimum. What should be my values for Initial Capacity and Load Factor in this case?

Comment: It depends on how the input keys differ from each other. Maybe they are from a small interval [1, ..., n], then it will be difficult.

Comment: You'll be surprised how little the rehashing matters. Test and measure with the defaults to establish whether you really have a problem first.

Comment: @EJP - yes, rehashing is generally a fast operation and in particular if you needed to `put` all those values in the map in the first place, it is very likely going to be a small portion of the total runtime (just generating that many objects is takes more time). That said, there are use-cases where "average `put`" time or "total runtime" aren't the right metrics: you may be interested in more the outlier response times, and rehashing of giant arrays can be a big source of outliers, esp. if they've tuned the other latency causes ... but java doesn't seem like a great language for that use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you know the maximum number of entries `n` you'll have in your  map, to avoid resizes you can set `capacity` to `n / loadFactor`. You set the load factor to some value which reflects your particular desires in space/time tradeoff space. If you aren't sure what load factor is best, the default of `0.75` is probably a fine place to start.

The key takeaway is that `capacity` is ***not*** the number of elements that the hash map will accept before it resizes, but rather the size of the underlying array. The hash map will accept `loadFactor * capacity` elements before it resizes. So you need to include `loadFactor` in your calculations for capacity.

To be concrete, if you are using the default `loadFactor` of `0.75` and you know your map will contain 1,000,000 elements, you must set capacity to `1e6 / 0.75 = ~1,333,334` elements to avoid resizing. If you aren't sure of the *exact* size it may make sense to include a buffer so you can be reasonable certain of avoiding resizing.

*Arguably* a better API would have been to directly define the `capacity` parameter as the number of elements that can be added to the set before resizing, and then the constructor does whatever calculation is necessary to set it's internal threshold member correctly. That would be consistent with the meaning of "capacity" for other structures, such as `ArrayList`.

Comment: To be more precise, if you know the *exact* number of entries up-front, and keep the default load factor of `0.75`, you do the capacity calculation using integer math, guarding against truncation, as follows: `capacity = size * 4 / 3 + 1`

Comment: Yes, I glossed over that part. The current implementation rounds up to the next power of two anyway, so being off by 1 or 2 (or even 100k for 10m element table) is not likely to cause an issue with the current implementation, but of course you probably shouldn't rely on that. @Andreas

Comment: @user7487304 - that sounds like a good (separate) question! Why don't you ask it and link to it here and I'll have a shot at it?

Comment: Suppose I want to store 1000 objects in hashmap, so in that case what would be the impact on performance of the HashMap if it is initialized with load factor value of "1" . or a small load factor of .1....
I would be interested  to know its effect on HahMap performance and the time taken for get/put operation for both scenarios(for load factor 1 and .1 and initial capacity 1000).. 
also can we have a loadfactor value greater than 1

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Since Im new to this forum and Im just aware of basic functionalities like asking question and all...dont know how to link..It would be highly appreciated if you can please do the same on my behalf or tell me the steps for the same.Looking forward to you answer and thanx in advance for help

Comment: Just copy and paste the URL into a comment works OK. The link really isn't important. If you want to do it, you can do it like `[LINK TEXT](LINK URL)` and it will make a link. See the [the help for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links).